# Подключение бд к Django

Tags: python, django

Всем привет. Начал изучать Django. В файле settings.py есть возможность настроить бд:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')
},
}
```

Данная бд используется по умолчанию. Я хочу подключить свою базу данных и вот мои настройки:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')
},

'r1': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'test',
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': '1234',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '3306',
}
```

}

При попытке сделать модели на основе данной бд с помощью `python manage.py inspectdb` ничего не происходит, кроме вывода информационного сообщения.

Во всех проектах, которые я видел, почему-то все используют дефолтную бд. Неужели невозможно подключить стороннюю?

Comment: А [документацию](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/)  видели? Конечно возможно.

Comment: Видел, но у меня не получается сделать модели на основе мой бд с помощью inspectdb. Не понимаю в чём причина...

Comment: Если видели, то почему не используете ключ `--database`?

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Запутался во всём этом, пытался найти примеры в книгах, реальных проектах на джанго , в интернете, а документацию невнимательно изучил:( в итоге пару дней ушло на решение проблемы. Ещё раз большое спасибо! 
Прошу оставить ваш комментарий в ответах:)